# How to combine two layers in keras using specific weights and biasses?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tflearn

I am trying to rewrite a piece of tflearn code using Keras.

The goals is to combine two inputs where one input skips the first layer. The following code works in tflearn:

```
    # Two different inputs.
    inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 10])
    action = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 10])

    #First layer used only by the inputs
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(inputs, 400, activation='relu')

    # Add the action tensor in the 2nd hidden layer
    # Use two temp layers to get the corresponding weights and biases
    t1 = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 300)
    t2 = tflearn.fully_connected(action, 300)

    # Combine the two layers using the weights from t1 and t2 and the bias from t2
    net = tflearn.activation(tf.matmul(net,t1.W) + tf.matmul(action, t2.W) + t2.b, activation='relu')
```

I am trying to replicate this code in Keras using the following code:

```
    # Two different inputs.
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    #First layer used only by the inputs
    t1 = Sequential()
    t1.add(Dense(400, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,10)))

    # Add the action tensor in the 2nd hidden layer
    # Use two temp layers to get the corresponding weights and biases
    t1.add(Dense(300))

    t2 = Sequential()
    t2.add(Dense(300, input_shape=(1,10)))

    # Combine the two layers
    critnet = Sequential()
    critnet.add(Merge([t1, t2], mode='sum'))
    critnet.add(Activation('relu'))

    # Create the net using the inputs and action placeholder
    net = critnet([inputs, action])
```

The code in keras behaves differently. How to combine two layers in keras in order to get the same result as in tflearn?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by behaves differently, but the two codes are very different. First you add a bias term in the tflearn code (non existent in keras code). Then, tflearn code ends with a ReLU activation (could be added to keras simply with an .add(activation('relu') ) ). And that comment at ``Use two temp layers to get the corresponding weights and biases``` makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you. The relu activation layer is indeed missing. I have added it. 

With the comment '' Use two temp layers to get the corresponding weights and biases'' It means that we can use the weights and biases from t1 and t2 to combine them and form a new layer.

In Keras we can merge layers using Merge as can be seen in the code however is there some way to merge them like it was done in the tflearn code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Lambda layer take takes your 2 layers as input and using keras.backend to merge them the same way. I think there is K.dot for matmul.